# Two step authentication in symfony2

Tags: security, symfony, authentication

I need create login form to enter site. But not simple (username and password). First step - user enter phone, i`m need check phone number from database, if user with entered phone number exists - generate random code and send to phne. Two step - check this code and if success - authenticate user in site. Standart symfony2 functionality does not allow this. Help me pleace with this issue)

Answer (score 3):

Here there is a blog post, what was listed on symfony's website, containing also a two factory authentication, back engineered from this sonata and google bundle:

http://www.christianscheb.de/archives/14

Comment: Looks like the link posted is not working, archive.org to the rescue:

http://web.archive.org/web/20160608090517/http://www.christianscheb.de/archives/14

Answer (score 1):

You could use the google_authenticator, which provides excacly this two step authentication mechanism. It's contained by the Sonata UserBundle: [Authenticator article in Sonata UserBundle documentation](http://www.sonata-project.org/bundles/user/2-0/doc/reference/two_step_validation.html)

And here is a nice blog post about it:
[Google Authenticator Blog Post](https://blog.liip.ch/archive/2011/08/29/2-step-verification-with-google-authenticator-and-php.html)